# За счет чего достигается криптостойкость в алгоритме Диффи-Хеллмана

Tags: алгоритм, криптография

1. Алиса возводит число 3 в степень А по модулю 17
2. Боб возводит число 3 в степень Б по модулю 17
3. далее они обмениваются результатами и довозводят полученные значения в свои секретные числа.

За счет чего достигается криптостойкость? По логике, что такое возведение в степень: это перемножить 3 А-раз и потом еще Б-раз. Взломщику, чтоб найти верный ключ, нужно так же перебирать - возвести 3 в степень 2 потом сравнить, далее в степень 3 и т.д. пока не найдет ответ. Тогда за счет чего достигается эффект, что взломщику это сделать на много сложнее.

Догадываюсь что зная конкретную степень возведение в нее занимает на много меньше времени чем банальный 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 и т.д. Это так?

Comment: Ева не знает ни a, ни b, она знает только остатки от деления.

Comment: во-первых, это не просто возведение в степень, а возведение в степень в конечном поле, а во-вторых, числа `a`, `b` и `p` (17) — БОЛЬШИЕ, т.е. действительно большие, порядка 4096 бит каждое. Как говорится, Ева принципиально не сможет перебрать значительную их часть на современном оборудовании раньше, чем наступит тепловая смерть вселенной... Ну или хотя бы за ближайшие сотню-другую лет...

Comment: @gbg Да, я понимаю. Я про то что например что нужно мне чтобы возвести 3 в степень 5 и найти по модулю 17, я делаю 3*3*3*3*3 и потом нахожу по модулю. Что нужно взломщику зная мой ответ, ему нужно проделать тоже самое но после каждого 3*3 проверять результат сравнивая с мои?

Comment: @Fat-Zer то что числа большие это понятно, но ведь и изначально Алиса и Боб так же оперируют этими большими числами, соотвественно они проделывают тоже примерно такие же вычисления. Я не до конца понимаю за счет чего у Алисы и Боба это получается на много быстрее. Если человеку нужно возвести 3 в степень 5 он сделает 3*3*3*3*3 если я знаю ответ 243 как мне найти степень, мне нужно сделать тоже самое только параллельно сравнивать не получилось ли у меня 243 после следующей итерации.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, как уже написали ниже, для возведения в степень числа подряд, конечно ни кто не перемножает — есть алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень; в самом простом случае — бинарное возведение в степень...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, Алиса и Боб умеют быстро вычислять степени. Пример из вашего вопроса: как вычислить `3*3*3*3*3` за меньшее число перемножений?

Сначала вычислим `3*3 = 9`. Затем вычислим `9*9 = 81`. В конце умножим `81*3 = 243`. Вместо 4-х умножений получилось сделать 3. Но это кажется смешным выигрышем только в случае, когда степени маленькие. Когда же дело доходит хотя бы до тысячной степени, выигрыш становится гораздо больше: 15 умножений против 1000. Дальше разрыв ещё больше. [Быстрое возведение в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) требует порядка `log(N)` операций умножения.

А злоумышленнику, который не знает, в какие степени возводили Алиса и Боб, приходится перебирать произведения в поисках значения. Эта задача называется [дискретным логарифмированием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и в общем случае не имеет эффективного алгоритма. Поэтому схема Диффи-Хеллмана считается надёжной. При больших размерах ключей вычисление ключей требует сотни перемножений, а обратная операция требует порядка квадратного корня из числа возможных произведений, что для современных эллиптических кривых означает перебор порядка `2^128` вариантов. На современных компьютерах это будет считаться бесконечно долго.

Comment: добавлю, что для задачи дискретного логарифмирования простой перебор — не единственный метод; есть и более эффективные, хотя время у всех всё равно экспоненциальное время... ну и элиптические кривые тут всё же не совсем к месту помянуты, когда речь об обычном алгоритме над полем вычетов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я решил не выпендриваться обширными знаниями. Вопрос явно новичковый,  а оценки трудоёмкости дискретного логарифмирования в Fp - дело мутное. Я хотел дать разумную оценку, но при этом не хотелось нагружать ответ L-нотацией и козырять фамилями Шенкса, Поллига и Ко. Отсюда и эллиптические кривые. Для них пока нет ничего лучше ро-метода Полларда с `O(sqrt(n))`, благодаря чему оценка трудоёмкости проста и наглядна. Да и вообще ECDHE используется в наши дни гораздо чаще, чем DHE, это дополнительный мотив упомянуть эллиптические кривые.

Comment: нум... мало-кто на вскидку помнит имена алгоритмов не говоря уже о том, в чём они заключаются, но то что есть способы (условно) быстрее простого перебора полезно ИМХО знать даже новичкам... ЗЫ: а ECDHE действительно часто используется? он просто первым в переговорах идёт в openssl'е? или его tls рекомендует?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, сорри что так долго думал над вашим комментарием ))) Спецификация TLS не требует использовать ECDHE. НО! Разработчики Хрома [директивно настаивают использовать TLS 1.2 c ECDHE](https://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Cipher-Suites). OpenSSL для TLS 1.2 первым выдаёт `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`. Для TLS 1.3 OpenSSL 1.1.x вообще не поддерживает DHE. Поэтому да, ECDHE - это устоявшаяся практика, стандар де-факто. Например, StackOverflow использует ECDHE над X25519

Comment: мм… ок… спасибо… лучше поздно чем никогда =)